# Text Columns should be moved towards end?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, memory-alignment

Is there any difference between speed of fetching data if dynamic rows is moved towards end.

example : int , int , int , text is better than int int text int ?

my lead has informed me about this fact , how ever no such information is getting from internet ? please help ?

Comment: I would be *very* suprised if you can actually measure the performance difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to data alignment. `INT` takes 4 bytes, so 32-bit (equivalent to 4 bytes) processors will work with data in 4 byte sequences. Being able to pull off the data in an order that best suits the processor will lead to faster results and better performance.

**Reference**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Now, this is a problem often found in transferring data over a communication channel (because certain compilers will typically optimize your data structure by adding a reserved byte to 4-byte align certain members). However, MySQL also takes 4-byte alignment into account with `NDBCLUSTER` engines. This means that by placing your `TEXT` structure in between the `INT` values, you force more data retrieval than necessary.

Thus:

`INT` `INT` `INT` `INT` `TEXT` will process faster than `INT` `INT` `TEXT` `INT` `INT` as the processor can retrieve 16-bytes (the four `INT`) immediately without worrying about the size of `TEXT`.

For more details, see the **MySQL documentation**:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

`TEXT` and `BLOB` data are not stored in the same space as the column itself. They're stored in a special area reserved for this purpose.

These columns are *always* slower to retrieve, but the amount of slow-down varies considerably depending on your system tuning and data load. Sometimes it's irrelevant, and sometimes it results in serious thrashing. Just be advised that you should use a short `VARCHAR` field over a `TEXT` field if you can manage it, that the vastly longer length of the blob fields does not come for free.

That being said, `TEXT` columns are stored in the row as pointer to the actual data which makes them significantly smaller than `VARCHAR` in most circumstances. If you don't select them, they don't get loaded, and you don't incur the additional seeking required to assemble their data.

To be sure this applies to your version of MySQL and your tuning, build two large tables full of representative data and benchmark it yourself.